# What does the % inside a string do in Python?

Tags: python, string, operators, computer-science

```
def leakyPipes(n):
if (n > 0):
    if (n % 4 == 0):
        print("drip %d" % n)
        leakyPipes(n-3)
    if (n % 3 == 0):
        print("drop %d" % n)
leakyPipes(12)
```

What is each of the % in print("drip %d" % n) supposed to do in this situation? The terminal output is giving me this:

```
drip 12
drop 9
drop 12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a formatting specifier.
`%d` would mean digit,
`%s` would mean string, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using that method (using % formatter) is not that great.

A better choice would be to use "str.format" or better yet f-string

You problem, and the 2 other options are outlined on the following page.

[Python String Formatting Options](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Answer (score 0):

The `%d` is used to specify the format, `%d` means a digit and `%s` means a string. The `%` that is used after the " is used so the program knows that `n` should be placed on the format specifier. Equally, you could use `print("drop", n)`.\

A useful link could be: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-print-variable/